# Error executing action `create` on resource 'cron[cron_name]'

Tags: cron, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I cannot get this cron job to get started. I am running opsworks instances and this is my recipe:

```rb
cron "delete_error_log" do
  hour "12"
  minute "30"
  command %Q{
  sudo find /srv/www/ -name "error_log" -delete
  }
  action :create
end
```

I have made sure that the cron would work by running inside ssh.

The error I am getting is this:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'cron[delete_error_log]'
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::Cron
----------------------
Error updating state of delete_error_log, exit: 1


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20140423133810_223/site-cookbooks/cron_job/recipes/delete_error_log.rb

1: cron "delete_error_log" do
2:   hour "12"
3:   minute "30"
4:   command %Q{
5:   sudo find /srv/www/ -name "error_log" -delete
6:   }
7:   action :create
8: end


Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20140423133810_223/site-cookbooks/cron_job/recipes/delete_error_log.rb:1:in `from_file'

cron("delete_error_log") do
weekday "*"
retry_delay 2
command "\n  sudo find /srv/www/ -name \"error_log\" -delete\n  "
minute "30"
cookbook_name :cron_job
month "*"
retries 0
recipe_name "delete_error_log"
day "*"
action [:create]
user "root"
hour "12"
end
=======================================================
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `command 'sudo find /srv/www/ -name "error_log" -delete'`? I see no reason to make it more complicated and it could be that the multi-line command is not correctly changed to a single line cron tab entry.

Comment: @gnat Thanks Stephen! That fixed it! I had tried using command "..." however the double quotes was thrown off by the "error_log" syntax, but single quotes worked perfectly. Thank you a ton! Deploying it now to all my instances! If you repost it as an answer I will mark it as the answer to the question - at least if my profile will let me (im new to stackoverflow)

Comment: Thanks! I would post it as an answer. I hope it's okay that I stripped down your question to the core problem and removed the `metadata.rb` etc. that does not have any influence. I think this problem could affect more chef users.. I think if chef would be working totally perfect, it would even replace the line breaks :-)

Comment: If you want to use double quotes instead of single ones, you would have to escape the inner ones (`"sudo .. \"...\" ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the multi-line command, which seems to be directly put into the crontab files. Instead, supply the `command` like this:

```rb
cron "delete_error_log" do
  hour "12"
  minute "30"
  command 'sudo find /srv/www/ -name "error_log" -delete'
end
```